# ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Admin\AdminAuthController does not exist laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, autenticación

Tengo este error que me sale cuando quiero llamar al metodo de autenticación del administrador,estoy desarrollando mis propios controladores y no se si es que no detecta bien la ruta o no encuetra la función.
Mi código esta así:

Este es el formulario de inicio que dependiendo del usuario es la opción de formulario que elige, por ahora solo estoy dedicandome al administrador

```html
<div class="border" style="margin: 10px; border:2px; width: 40rem; height: 26.5rem;">
          <h1 style="text-align: center;">Inicio de sesión</h1>
          <p style="margin: 5px;">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#adminform" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
              Administradores
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#coordinatorform" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
              Coordinadores
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#teacherform" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
              Profesores
            </a>
          </p>
          <div class="collapse" id="adminform">
            <div class="card card-body">
              <form action="{{route('admin.login')}}" method="POST">
                  @csrf
                  <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label>Cédula:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name = "cedula" placeholder="Ingrese su cédula" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label>Contraseña:</label>
                    <input type="password"class="form-control" name = "password" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submint">Iniciar sesión</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse" id="coordinatorform">
            <div class="card card-body">
              <form action="" method="GET">
                  @csrf
                  <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label>Cédula:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name = "cedula" placeholder="Ingrese su cédula">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label>Contraseña:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name = "password"placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submint">Iniciar sesión</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse" id="teacherform">
            <div class="card card-body">
              <form action="" method="GET">
                  @csrf
                  <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label>Cédula:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name = "cedula" placeholder="Ingrese su cédula">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label>Contraseña:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name = "password"placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submint">Iniciar sesión</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>      
      </div>
```

Las rutas las tengo definidas así:

```html
Route::post('/','Auth\Admin\AdminAuthController@adminlogin')->name('admin.login');
Route::get('/','Auth\Admin\AdminAuthController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
```

y al ejecutar el comando `php artisan route:list` me salta el error del título, ya lei toda la documentación al respecto y estuve investigando casos similares pero no importa lo que implemente no funciona.

Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradeceria mucho

Comment: verifica los namespaces del controlador y las rutas. En el controlador debería ser algo así: `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Admin;`

Comment: A que te refieres con namespace? porque asi lo tengo, cuando me marca el error me marca bien las carpetas de donde está mi controlador, asi que no se que debería corregir

Comment: en el controlador al inicio se declara el namespace, para tu caso debería se el que te pasé. Puedes agregar las primeras líneas de tu controlador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegúrate que AdminAuthController exista y tenga correctamente seteado el namespace:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminAuthController extends Controller
{
    ...
}
```